# Corona SDK Live RayCasting

Tags: raycasting

I'm looking for help involving rayCast in Corona SDK. If you haven't see it here's a link talking about it along with a demo. WEll in the demo you tap on a space and the ray is recasted and bounced if possible. What I'm trying to do and have failed to figure out is if it would be possible to have this rayCast done live? For example a scenario this would be helpful...
http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/05/07/physics-raycasting-and-reflection/

A 2D shooter with a laser sight - you move your finger to aim and the red dot on the receiving end of the bullet shows live where in the level you're aiming. So if I drag my finger down to aim down, I see the laser dot correlate with my finger. Is this possible?

If that doesn't make sense, we can use the demo. You tap and the laser updates its path. Would it be possible to drag your finger and see the path update and reflect in real time?

Thank you very much to anyone who can help with my issue. I've seen this sort of thing done in other games but there's no telling what engine or alternative method they used. Thanks again for your time.